# Prove unit ball is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

let $(l^{1}(\mathbb Z), || .||_{1})$ be a norm space where $l^{1}(\mathbb Z):=\{x=(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb Z}\subset\mathbb C : ||x||_{1}<\infty \}$

a.) Show that $\overline{B_{1}(0)}$ is closed and bounded.

b.) Show that $\overline{B_{1}(0)}$ is not compact.

My thoughts:
In terms of $a.)$ proving that it is bounded is easiest. Consider $\overline{B_{1}(0)}:=\{x\in l^{1}(\mathbb Z):||x-0||_{1}\leq1\}$, this means $\exists c > 1 $: $\forall x\in \overline{B_{1}(0)}$: $||x||_{1}<1<c$, so it is bounded.

I'm struggling in terms of closedness, how do I prove that $l^{1}(\mathbb Z)/ (\overline{B_{1}(0)})$ is open?

Next, how can I prove that $\overline{B_{1}(0)}$ is not compact? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Suppose x is a sequence that is NOT in $l^1(Z)$.  What does that tell you about $x_1$?

Comment: That $||x||_{1}=\infty$

Comment: You state this as if it is for an arbitrary norm on $\ell_1(\Bbb Z)$, but you use the particular notation $\|\cdot\|_1$, which normally applies to a specific norm: the supremum norm. Do you really mean an arbitrary norm, or do you want the supremum norm here?